# C# how would i split a 2D array into an arbitrary amount of 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have the following script and am trying to determine how to split this into smaller chunks to assign to the various terrains it is filling.

```
public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    private void ApplyHeights(float[,] hts) {
        for(int x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < zSize; z++) {
                float[,] h = new float[template.terrainData.heightMapWidth, template.terrainData.heightMapHeight];
                h = Split2DFloatArray(template.terrainData.heightMapWidth, template.terrainData.heightMapHeight,x*template.terrainData.heightMapWidth, z*template.terrainData.heightMapHeight);
    }
}
```

However I have been unable to find an appropriate method for grabbing 'chunks' and copying them to separate arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't split a 2D array. However, you can copy pieces from it to new and potentially smaller 2D arrays.

Comment: @Vikhram that is exactly what I am looking to do, I've just been unable to figure out how to tell it where to start each chunk in the larger array to copy its values to the smaller array.

Comment: For now, your question has a lot of unrelated code. If you can remove the unrelated code and tell us how do you want to split the array `data[rows, columns]`, I might be able to help. In fact, imagine there exists a function that does exactly what you want. You need to write the code for that and what you don't know write pseudo code

Comment: I notice you've edited your question 9 hours ago. Did you happen to look at my answer?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I did notice your answer and have not yet had to chance to check it out

Comment: All right, well since I submitted my answer before you edited your question, let me know if you'd like me to edit my answer to include a separate `Split2DFloatArray()` method.

Comment: @Jdoonan, it's been several days since we've heard from you. Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: apologies, yes it did resolve my problem, and life events had me unable to be online these last couple months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
private void ApplyHeights(float[,] hts)
{
    int hwidth = template.terrainData.heightMapWidth;
    int hheight = template.terrainData.heightMapHeight;
    for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            float[,] h = new float[hwidth, hheight];
            int offsetX = x * hwidth;
            int offsetZ = z * hheight;
            for (int hx = 0; hx < hwidth; hx++)
            {
                for (int hz = 0; hz < hheight; hz++)
                {
                    h[hx, hz] = hts[offsetX + hx, offsetZ + hz];
                }
            }
            // Do something with h.
        }
    }
}
```